# Discussion Forum - Are template tags available for it?

Tags: forum, discussion

Based on the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/forum/other_features.html), `{exp:forum}` is available to show the forum in the templates.

But the problem here is that I want the forums to conform to the look and feel of my site.

Are there tags available for this module where we can get more control on the output(like a tag for the header, a tag for the list of boards, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are not. To style the forum you have to edit the theme files directly.

EllisLab's reommendation per [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/forum/forum_themes.html):

> If you plan to make changes to your theme, we recommend that you make
>   a copy of the themes/forum_themes/default/ directory, name it
>   something else, and make your changes to that one.

Instead of doing that, I suggest taking a look at [**Scaffold forum theme**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/scaffold) because it will almost certainly serve as a better starting point for your customization.